# Insert into Table2 only if values being inserted are found in Table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Table1 and Table2.

I use an insert on Table2 like below:

```
insert into table2    
(colOne, colTwo, colThree) //and many more cols 
  values 
(1, norman, US) //and many more values that come from a form and not table1
```

I'd like the insert to succeed only if values (1,norman, US) are present in Table1. Values (1,Norman,US) come from a form. How can I do something like this.

At present I used 2 steps to do this. One to check if the values exist, two - the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an `INSERT INTO... SELECT... WHERE`

Something liket that

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3)
select (1, 'norman', 'US') from Table1 t1 -- where 1, 'norman', 'US' are your variables from a Form
where t1.id=1 and t1.name = 'norman' and t1.country = 'US' -- same
```

little [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53356/1) demo for "select whatever I want".

Comment: The thing is, I cannot do the select there, because those 3 values are not the only ones being inserted. There's other data from a form. So: insert into table2 (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values (1,'norman','US','Form Field 1', 'Form Field 2'). Don't think I can use the select there. Or can I?

Comment: @Norman Yes you can : for me (see the comment in the query), 1, 'norman', and 'US' are fields from the form. If they weren't, I should have written `select t1.id, t1.name, t1.country` for example.

Comment: Woops! Was viewing your answer on mobile and the comment was cut off with no scroll bar.

Comment: @Norman added an SqlFiddle to show how "select any thing you'd like" work.

Comment: Yes. Thank You. Your solution works very well. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method :

```
INSERT INTO table2    
(colOne, colTwo, colThree)
SELECT colOne, colTwo, colThree 
FROM 
(SELECT 1  AS colOne,'norman' AS colTwo,'US' AS colThree
 UNION
 SELECT 2,'sabt','US' 
 UNION
 SELECT 3,'ebi','US' 
)p
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM table1
            WHERE table1.colOne = p.colOne AND 
                  table1.colTwo =p.colTwo AND 
                  table1.colThree =p.colThree
            )
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is normally done with triggers. Register an after insert trigger for table1 and do an insert for table2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189799.aspx